# Floor function proof :

Tags: proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am new to floor functions and I can't see a way to find this exact inequality. I have studied the cases but I'm more interested in being able to find this particular inequality.

$$  -2 \leq 3 \left \lfloor 2x \right \rfloor -2\left \lfloor 3x \right \rfloor \leq 1$$

Comment: Hint:All floors are integers.

Answer (score 2):

$2x-1<\lfloor 2x\rfloor\le2x\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

$3x-1<\lfloor 3x\rfloor\le3x\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

By multiplying $(*)$ by $3$ and by multiplying $(**)$ by $-2$, it follows that

$6x-3<3\lfloor 2x\rfloor\le6x$

$-6x\le-2\lfloor 3x\rfloor<-6x+2$

and, by adding the last two inequalities, we get that

$-3<3\lfloor 2x\rfloor -2\lfloor 3x\rfloor<2\;.$

Since $\;3\lfloor 2x\rfloor -2\lfloor 3x\rfloor\;$ is an integer, it follows that

$-2\le3\lfloor 2x\rfloor -2\lfloor 3x\rfloor\le1\;.$